# What is maximum limit of items in ssrs 2005 multi-value parameter

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am using SSRS 2005. I have one parameterised report. I am using 3,4 cascading parameters. my last parameter can have upto 5000 values in it. I want to know that what is the maximum limit of multi-value parameter becuase when i select deselect some parameters I got one error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." I wonder if it is due to lot of values in one of the parameter.

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: I have test it and found that for the last parameter is i select top 974 then it works fine. but I slection record greater then 974 then I got error message. I think 974 is the limit for multi-value parameter in ssrs 2005

Comment: I think the length limitation may be related to the length of the string produced (`'Value A','Value B',...`) so changing the value of your parameters may help slightly.

Comment: @Jamie F: Ahh - that would be an interesting thought. A quick calculation shows that if the string is of the form 1,2,3,4 then 1 to 974 would give a length of 3788. I'd not be suprised if the limit was 4000 characters and there're some spaces or something in there.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a source for a hard limit of number of parameters but to be honest if you're using 100s I think you're going to run into usability issues first.

I'd suggest grouping the options by one or two more cascading parameters that narrow down the range if that's possible for your application.

Comment: Hi Steve, you got me wrong. I am not talking about number of parameters. I am talking about number of items in a parameters. For example if there is 2 parameters in the report. One parameter name is "Select School" and other parameter name is "Select number of students" and if the 2nd parameter contain more then 974 students then u will get error.

Comment: Sorry I phrased the reply badly - yes I understood what you meant - I was thinking that having 100s of options in a drop down would be a problem. To limit the number of schools for example you could group them by initial letter in a separate combo box. If you've a parameter with a number you could allow the user to enter a range in a text box (100-500) for example and parse this out in your SQL.

Comment: You are right. But I want to know about the limit of items in a ssrs reprot multivalue parameter. Why I got error message when number of items is exceeded more then 974. "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.""

Comment: Jamie's comment sound reasonable - you could check by using profiler to look at the string passed from SSRS to the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://sqlsrv4living.blogspot.com/2012/10/sql-reporting-services-maximum-number.html)

*There is a constraint (on .NET framework or Web server I think) that allows only 1,000 values to be loaded under parameter drop down boxes*